# MediaMetaDataRetriever returns null on Android 10

Tags: android

I have retrieved all the audio files in the storage by querying the MediaStore. I wanted to fetch their album art, so I used MetaDataRetriever. It fetches all the album art on Android 9 and lower, but when on Android 10, the application crashes with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. What can I do for it?

Code;

```
private Bitmap getAlbumImage(String path) {
    android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(path);
    byte[] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
    if (data != null) return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    return null; //Works on Android 9 and lower
}
```

I also used `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in manifest application tag but then also the exception occurs

Comment: What's the targetSdkVersion you are using in the code

Comment: I am using targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: Hello @NitishChaudhary Kindly reply

Comment: Cause i am facing same situation

Comment: my targetSdkVersion version 30

Comment: @ElPrimo  Since you are targeting sdk 30 ,     android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"     is departed and no longer works.

Comment: You need update your query to fetch media from the storage . Refer to android docs for sample - [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#load-thumbnails).

Comment: I have queried to fetch media from the storage using uri, contentresolver and cursor using mediastore